# Saving server data to core data, in background thread issues

Tags: ios, json, swift, multithreading, core-data

I know the concurrency is really headache.I read so many articles about how to parse and save server data to core data.But many tutorials are very basic they are not apply with the thread.But  when we develop a app, the multithread is needed.

My app process are follows

1.Get data from server using URLSession
2.And parse
3.Save to core data - In background  , need to check for duplicates
4.Then fetch the data
5.Update UI.

Am stuck in  3rd step **Save to core data - In background  , need to check for duplicates**

I read that, URLSession is running in  background thread. Is need to use performblock as apple says ?https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

I tried in follwing way.But sometime it is crashed.It will be better anyone suggest the correct flow of programming.There are lot of questions regarding this but for this issue there is no a correct solution.

```
func DownloadFrom_server(dict:Any,urlstring_get:String)  {
    if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(dict) {
        do{
            let json:Data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

            var urlString = urlstring_get
            urlString =   urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed)!
            var httpRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
            httpRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
            httpRequest.httpBody = json
            let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            sessionConfig.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Accept" : "application/json", "api-key" : "API_KEY"]
            let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: httpRequest) { data, response, error in
                guard let data_get = data, error == nil else{// check for fundamental networking error
                    print("data nil\(error)")
                    //1.network connection lost
                    //save offline data
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data_get, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                    print("cloud data",jsonResult)
                    self.Save_server_Data_ToCoreData(jsonResult: jsonResult)
                }
                catch {
                    print("json result parsing error ",error)
                }  
            }
            task.resume()
        }   
        catch{ 
            print("InValidJSONObject json:Data error - ",error)
        }
    }
}
```

And saving server josn to core data as follows

```
func Save_server_Data_ToCoreData(jsonResult:Any)  {
    let context = getContext()
    let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateMOC.parent = context
    privateMOC.perform {
        if let data = jsonResult  as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
            //Heree prepare MOC
            // if i need to check data alredy exits or not means how can i check
        }
        do {
            try privateMOC.save()
          context.performAndWait {
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
   }

   DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        print("update main")
                    })
}
```

I have a second thought of doing in following way

```
             DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
//saving core data
 //fetching data
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   //update UI
}
     }
```

Not sure which context need to use, private or main.If anyone who answer for this question will be useful for so many beginners in Multithread like me.

Comment: Try MagicalRecord : https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Answer (score 1):

For Duplicity check in core data. Above ios9 there is a unique constraint feature in Coredata.

Set property name in constraints of Entity description like id,name etc

[image]

and in managedobjectcontext set merge policy to NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

Remember that above duplicity check feature doesn't work if you have relationship in your Entities(I have check it in xcode7.3).

Answer (score 0):

You can a function that will check or create new one by unique field such as `id`. If let say record already exist, then either can skip or update fields, but not creating new record. (Make sure your entity have unique field for primary key)

You can call this when looping the data received from server API

```
func findOrCreate(byId objectId: String) -> NSManagedObject {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Document")

    // Create a new predicate that filters out any object that equal to this id
    print("looking for id: \(objectId)")

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "objectId == %@", objectId)

    // Set the predicate on the fetch request
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do {

        // if found in core data
        let results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if !results.isEmpty {
            return results.first as! NSManagedObject
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not create object \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    // else create new object
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "DocumentEntity", in:managedObjectContext)

    let newObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

    return newObject
}
```

Comment: Thank you.But am talking about Multithreading.Not for checking duplicate.